# Error while running coredova app

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am getting "No targets to build against" while running the coredova sample application on android emulator.
My Android applications are running fine.
Please let me know where to set the target for the coredova app.
I am using JBoss Hybrid mobile(cordova) plugin in eclipse.
my OS is windows 32-bit
I have posted a snap here http://i61.tinypic.com/301q3hu.png 
Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Chandan kumar

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post the error stacktrace so get to get a quicker answer from the community. Also post the specfic details of your environment to get a quicker response.

Comment: it is showing dialog saying that "No target to build against" when i click on run using android emulator/device